# How can you tell which characters are in which character classes?

Tags: awk

We often see people ask questions about why their string doesn't match their regexp and sometimes the answer comes down to them expecting a character to be part of a character class when it isn't or them trying to use a shorthand for  a character class (e.g. `\d` for `[[:digit:]]`) that exists in some other tool but simply isn't part of the awk language. So with that in mind I'm creating a canonical answer to the question of which characters exist in which character classes in awk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following script will generate the set of chars in each character class (plus the \s, \S, \w, and \W extensions if your awk supports them) for your locale for the chars in the numeric range 0-127 as listed in the first table at http://www.asciitable.com/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII. For a horizontal tab character as output by `print "\t"` the first reference uses TAB and the other HT as the abbreviation - I prefer TAB so I used it below. They both use `Space` to represent the char output by `print " "` so I also did that below even though I more commonly refer to it as a "blank char":

```
$ cat prtCharClasses.awk
# From the gawk manual, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions:
#   [:alnum:]   Alphanumeric characters
#   [:alpha:]   Alphabetic characters
#   [:blank:]   Space and TAB characters
#   [:cntrl:]   Control characters
#   [:digit:]   Numeric characters
#   [:graph:]   Characters that are both printable and visible (a space is printable but not visible, whereas an ‘a’ is both)
#   [:lower:]   Lowercase alphabetic characters
#   [:print:]   Printable characters (characters that are not control characters)
#   [:punct:]   Punctuation characters (characters that are not letters, digits, control characters, or space characters)
#   [:space:]   Space characters (these are: space, TAB, newline, carriage return, formfeed and vertical tab)
#   [:upper:]   Uppercase alphabetic characters
#   [:xdigit:]  Characters that are hexadecimal digits
#   \s          Matches any whitespace character. Think of it as shorthand for ‘[[:space:]]’.
#   \S          Matches any character that is not whitespace. Think of it as shorthand for ‘[^[:space:]]’.
#   \w          Matches any word-constituent character—that is, it matches any letter, digit, or underscore. Think of it as shorthand for ‘[[:alnum:]_]’.
#   \W          Matches any character that is not word-constituent. Think of it as shorthand for ‘[^[:alnum:]_]’.

BEGIN {
    asciiMax = (asciiMax == "" ? 127 : asciiMax)

    numClasses = split("\
        [[:alpha:]]     \
        [[:digit:]]     \
        [[:alnum:]]     \
        [[:lower:]]     \
        [[:upper:]]     \
        [[:xdigit:]]    \
        [[:punct:]]     \
        [[:cntrl:]]     \
        [[:graph:]]     \
        [[:print:]]     \
        [[:blank:]]     \
        [[:space:]]     \
        \\s             \
        \\S             \
        \\w             \
        \\W             \
    ", classes)

    # Map the control chars and white space in the 0-127 range to
    # their abbreviations to make them visible in the output:
    split("NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS TAB LF VT FF CR SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US Space", map)
    map[128] = "DEL"

    for (asciiNr=0; asciiNr<=asciiMax; asciiNr++) {
        char = sprintf("%c", asciiNr)
        chars[++numChars] = char
    }

    for (classNr in classes) {
        class = classes[classNr]
        for (charNr in chars) {
            char = chars[charNr]
            if ( char ~ class ) {
                classChars[classNr,charNr]
            }
        }
    }

    for (classNr=1; classNr<=numClasses; classNr++) {
        class = classes[classNr]
        printf "%-12s =", class
        for (charNr=1; charNr<=numChars; charNr++) {
            if ( (classNr,charNr) in classChars ) {
                char = chars[charNr]
                printf " %s", (charNr in map ? map[charNr] : char)
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Here is it's output for chars 0-127 in the C locale, if you have a different locale then the output will be different so run the above script to see what it is in your locale:

```
$ awk -f prtCharClasses.awk file
[[:alpha:]]  = A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
[[:digit:]]  = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[[:alnum:]]  = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
[[:lower:]]  = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
[[:upper:]]  = A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
[[:xdigit:]] = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F a b c d e f
[[:punct:]]  = ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
[[:cntrl:]]  = NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS TAB LF VT FF CR SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US DEL
[[:graph:]]  = ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
[[:print:]]  = Space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
[[:blank:]]  = TAB Space
[[:space:]]  = TAB LF VT FF CR Space
\s           = TAB LF VT FF CR Space
\S           = NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ DEL
\w           = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
\W           = NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS TAB LF VT FF CR SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US Space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ ` { | } ~ DEL
```

Note that `\s`, `\S`, `\w`, and `\W` are extensions only available in some tools, e.g. GNU awk. `\d` and `\D` are not present above - those are extensions available in some tools that support PCREs as shorthand for `[:digit:]` but that does not include any variant of awk. If you want a shorthand for `[:digit:]` then `[0-9]` appears to be portable across locales but I stand to be corrected.

If you need to see the chars past number 127, then you can set `asciiMax` on the command line, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v asciiMax=255 -f prtCharClasses.awk
[[:alpha:]]  = A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ª µ º À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
[[:digit:]]  = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[[:alnum:]]  = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ª µ º À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
[[:lower:]]  = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z µ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
[[:upper:]]  = A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ
[[:xdigit:]] = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F a b c d e f
[[:punct:]]  = ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ ¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © « ¬ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ ¶ · ¸ ¹ » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ × ÷
[[:cntrl:]]  = NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS TAB LF VT FF CR SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US DEL                                
[[:graph:]]  = ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ ¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
[[:print:]]  = Space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~   ¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
[[:blank:]]  = TAB Space  
[[:space:]]  = TAB LF VT FF CR Space  
\s           = TAB LF VT FF CR Space  
\S           = NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ DEL                                 ¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ­ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
\w           = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ª µ º À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
\W           = NUL SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS TAB LF VT FF CR SO SI DLE DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US Space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ ` { | } ~ DEL                                   ¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © « ¬ ­ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ ¶ · ¸ ¹ » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿ × ÷
```

Comment: Nice response. You detail `\w` and `\W`, but what about `\y` and `\B`? Am confused when to choose "character that is not word-constituent" vs "empty string at either the beginning or the end of a word" or "between two word-constituent characters" as per my comment response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57319339/598141)

Comment: Thanks. idk what those mean - you could always add them to the script and run it to see what your awk makes of them.

Comment: It's defined under [3.7 gawk-Specific Regexp Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators) . I always have difficulty figuring out whether to have a matching or not matching for outside of phrases (ie: word boundaries). Trial and error is my standby

Comment: @IanW Ah, I see. I always use `\<` and `\>` instead of `\y` and I haven't had a use for `\B` yet. The difference between those and the escape sequences in my answer is that they are not sets of characters but instead indicate boundaries between characters - they're more like `^` and `$` than `\s`, `\S`, `\w`, and `\W`. Wrt which to use when - if you post a question I'm sure someone can help you.