# Making a KO annotation table from eggnog mapper output

Tags: bash, awk

I have an annotation table from eggnog mapper and need to make this KO table:

```
Gene    evalue    KO
Gene1   0.00003   KO0000
Gene2   0.00005   KO0001
Gene2   0.00005   KO0003
Gene3   0.000005  KO0002
```

This is the table I have (test.txt):

```
Gene    evalue    KO
Gene1   0.00003   KO0000
Gene2   0.00005   KO0001,KO0003
Gene3   0.000005  KO0002
```

I have ~17,000 rows and the output is in xlsx format. The first issue I am having is that when I save the output file as a txt and view in linux (`head test.txt`) some of the columns look like this:

```
Gene,evalue,KO
Gene1  0.00003  KO0000
Gene2  0.0005   "KO0001,KO0003"
Gene3  0.00005  KO0002
```

How can I remove the quotes around these values? And how can I make the annotation table above?

I have tried this script from this thread ([How can I split comma separated values into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705187/how-can-i-split-comma-separated-values-into-multiple-rows))

```
awk ' BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
     { $1=$1;t=$0; }
     { while(index($0,",")) {
         gsub(/,[[:alnum:],]*/,""); print;
         $0=t; gsub(OFS "[[:alnum:]]*,",OFS); t=$0;
       }
       print t
     }' file
```

But it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop because of the quotes around the values in the third column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your 'infinite loop' issue using your `awk` code. (In fact, there was no output generated at all from the code).  Here is an alternative `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} \
NR==1{gsub(",",OFS,$0); print} \
(NR>1 && $0 ~ /,/) {gsub("\"","",$3); split($3,a,","); $3=""; for (i in a) {print $0 a[i]}} \
(NR>1 && $3!=""){print $0}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
Gene    evalue  KO
Gene1  0.00003  KO0000
Gene2   0.0005  KO0003
Gene2   0.0005  KO0001
Gene3  0.00005  KO0002
```

To match your expected output formatting more exactly, pipe the `awk` output to `column -t`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} \
NR==1{gsub(",",OFS,$0); print} \
(NR>1 && $0 ~ /,/) {gsub("\"","",$3); split($3,a,","); $3=""; for (i in a) {print $0 a[i]}} \
(NR>1 && $3!=""){print $0}' tt.txt | column -t
```

Output:

```
Gene   evalue   KO
Gene1  0.00003  KO0000
Gene2  0.0005   KO0003
Gene2  0.0005   KO0001
Gene3  0.00005  KO0002
```

Explanation:

Set output field separator to tab character

```
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
```

Change commas in first record to output field separator (tab character) and print the first record

```
NR==1{gsub(",",OFS,$0); print}
```

For each row after the first row that has commas in the row: 1) remove all double quotes, 2) split the third column into an array on comma characters, 3) set the 3 column to empty string, 4) print output for each of the items in the array.

```
(NR>1 && $0 ~ /,/) {gsub("\"","",$3); split($3,a,","); $3=""; for (i in a) {print $0 a[i]}}
```

Print all rows after first row where 3rd column is not empty.

```
(NR>1 && $3!=""){print $0}'
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. I honestly have no idea how I managed to get it stuck in a loop, I'm still new to awk. Would you be able to explain the second code a bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always structured like this, and multiple values are between double quotes separated by a comma, you might use [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) to define the content of the fields using `gnu awk`

The contents of the fields is determined by the pattern:

```
"[^"]*"|[^[:space:],]+
```

The pattern matches either from `"..."` OR 1+ non whitespace chars other than a comma.

Then you can print the first 2 fields, and for the 3rd field check if there is a comma. If there is, the first part of the pattern matched with the double quotes, as that one it the only part that can contain a comma.

Then you can split on either `"` or `,` using a character class. Print all the values returned by the split, and discard the first and the last entry in the loop as those are caused by the double quotes.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^[:space:],]+' '
{
  start = $1 OFS $2
  if (index($3, ",")) {
    n=split($3, a,/[,"]/)
    for(i=2;i<n;i++) print start OFS a[i]
    next
  }
  print start OFS $3  
}
' file
```

Output

```
Gene    evalue  KO
Gene1   0.00003 KO0000
Gene2   0.0005  KO0001
Gene2   0.0005  KO0003
Gene3   0.00005 KO0002
```