# Remove special characters from 2nd column of a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cat, tr

I have a file **s.csv**

```
a,b+ -.,c 
aa,bb ().,c._c
```

I want to remove all special characters from 2nd column (file separated by comma)

```
cat s.csv | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

The above code also removes special characters from 3rd column as well.

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' s.csv | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

This code only print 2nd column.

Any idea how can I remove special char from 2nd column and price all

Required output should be

```
a,b,c 
aa,bb,c._c
```

Comment: Your code `tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r'` means you want to retain `\n`s when they appear in your 2nd column. That implies you can have `\n`s in your 2nd column. Given that, none of the line-oriented approaches so far can work. Please [edit] your question to tell is for sure if your fields can contain **newlines or commas** and show sample input/output that includes such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all (from second field)

1. characters that are not upper case letters `[^A-Z`
2. or lower case letters `a-z`
3. or digits `0-9]`
4. from second field `$2`
5. fields are with "," separated `-F ','`
6. keep the separator in output `OFS=FS`

---

```
$ awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/,"",$2); print}' s.csv


# test
$ awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/,"",$2); print}' <<<'aa,bb ().,c._c'
aa,bb,c._c
```

As @Léa Gris mentioned below

> Don't forget to set the locale to `C` or `[^A-Za-z0-9]` is gonna be
> interpreted unexpectedly in non-western European alphabets. Prepend
> awk invocation with
> `LC_ALL=C`

Comment: Don't forget to set the locale to `C` or `[^A-Za-z0-9]` is gonna be interpreted unexpectedly in non-western European alphabets. Prepend awk invocation with `LC_ALL=C`, like `LC_ALL=C awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/,"",$2); print}' s.csv`. Unfortunately, there is no way to change the locale settings within an awk script, so the locale settings need to be set before running awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[:alpha:]` character class using `awk`, here for second field and remove with `gsub()` function the characteres that aren't alpha:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/, "", $2)} 1' file
a,b,c
aa,bb,c._c
```

- if you need other set of characters, you can see this answer of Ed Morton:
  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481541/how-can-you-tell-which-characters-are-in-which-character-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481541/how-can-you-tell-which-characters-are-in-which-character-classes%20%20and%20see)
  and see "which characters are in which character classes"

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F',' -lane '$F[1] =~ s{[\W_]+}{}g; @F = map { lc } @F; print join ",", @F; ' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F','` : Split into `@F` on comma, rather than on whitespace.

`s{[\W_]+}{}` : Replace 1 or more occurrences of `\W` (non-word character) or underscore with nothing.

The regex uses these modifiers:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** have to alter `locale` just to do it - by using `octals` instead of letters, the regex engine respects them as `ASCII` instead of being overly clever - i even intentionally set it to Belgian French to illustrate :

**CODE**

```
echo 'a,b+ -.,c 
aa,bb ().,c._c' | {m,g}awk '

gsub("[^\\060-\\071\\101-\\132\\141-\\172]+","",$(!_+!_))^_' \
                                              OFS=',' FS=','
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a,b,c 
aa,bb,c._c
```

**SHOWCASE** `LOCALE=C` **isn't needed**

```
 LANG="fr_BE.UTF8" gawk -e '
 BEGIN { for(_=8*4;_<8^4;_++) { printf("%c",_) } } ' | 
 
 LANG="fr_BE.UTF8" gawk -p- -e '
 gsub("[^\\060-\\071\\101-\\132\\141-\\172]+","",$-_)^_' OFS=',' FS=','
```

——————————

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

# profile gawk, cr'e'e Sun May 29 05:58:26 2022

# R`egle(s)

 1  (gsub("[^\\060-\\071\\101-\\132\\141-\\172]+", "", $-_)) ^ _ { # 1
 1      print
}
```